# Parsing JSON array in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to parse JSON file to show in table view in Swift 3 without using external frameworks, but my knowledge in Swift is not enough. I have looked other questions, but nothing worked for me. The problem is that in my JSON there are couple of nested arrays.
Here is example of the JSON file:

```
"guides" : [
    {
        "name" : "First Guide",
        "sections" : [
            {
                "title" : "Controls",
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "controls.PNG",
                        "type" : "image"
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "Sensitivity:  Changes the sensitivity of the camera when turning.",
                        "type" : "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "Invert Y-Axis: Toggles inversion of camera when looking up/down.",
                        "type" : "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "crosshair.PNG",
                        "type" : "image"
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "Lefty : Toggles the D-pad being on the left/right side of the screen.",
                        "type" : "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "Swap Jump and Sneak : Chooses whether to swap the position of jump and sneak buttons.",
                        "type" : "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "Button size - Changes the size of the buttons. Smaller buttons allow extra slots for the hotbar.",
                        "type" : "text"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title" : "User Profile",
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "profile.png",
                        "type" : "image"
                    },
                    {
                        "value" : "Use Cellular Data: Gives the Player the option to use cellular data.",
                        "type" : "text"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title" : "Global Resources",
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "value" : "resources.png",
                        "type" : "image"
                    },
```

..............

How I get parse the data into Swift arrays and use it to be displayed in UITableView controller. There are couple of "guides" in this JSON and I need to be able to show only one of them at the time.
 Help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are countless existing examples of parsing JSON data. Please update your question with relevant code showing what you actually tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing json into an array in swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759998/parsing-json-into-an-array-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code:

```
let jsonString = "[\"a\",\"b\"]"
        let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)! as Data
        do {
            let dataJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers)
            print(dataJson)
        }
        catch {
            print("error getting xml string: \(error)")
        }
```